# Enumerate tuple & store the information

Tags: python

How can i enumerate a tuple of months and actually store that information for later use?

```
months = ( '==========', 'Ιανουάριος', 'Φεβρουάριος', 'Μάρτιος', 'Απρίλιος', 'Μάϊος', 'Ιούνιος', 'Ιούλιος', 'Αύγουστος', 'Σεπτέμβριος', 'Οκτώβριος', 'Νοέμβριος', 'Δεκέμβριος' )
months = enumerate( months )
```

The above returns an error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found
```

Also, the enumerated data above must be stored in a way that some later code of mines usings months continue to be functional.

```
name = month = year = ''

# populate names, months, years
names.add( '====================' )
names = sorted( names )

months = ( '==========', 'Ιανουάριος', 'Φεβρουάριος', 'Μάρτιος', 'Απρίλιος', 'Μάϊος', 'Ιούνιος', 'Ιούλιος', 'Αύγουστος', 'Σεπτέμβριος', 'Οκτώβριος', 'Νοέμβριος', 'Δεκέμβριος' )

years  = ( '=====', 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019 )


pdata = pdata + '''
<br><h3><br><font color=gold size=6> Επιλεκτική Αναζήτηση </font><br>
<form method="POST" action="%s">
''' % url_for('seek')

pdata = pdata + '''<select name="name"><option>  %s </option></select>''' % '</option><option>'.join( names )

pdata = pdata + '''<select name="month"><option> %s </option></select>''' % '</option><option>'.join( months )

pdata = pdata + '''<select name="year"><option>  %s </option></select>''' % '</option><option>'.join( list( map( str, years ) ) )

pdata = pdata + '''
<br><input type="image" src="/static/img/submit.gif" name="seek" value="<Αναζήτηση>">
</form> <br><br>
'''

return pdata
```

Comment: It is the `join` that actually causes the error. `enumerate` returns an iterator over index-elmnt tuples, whereas join expects an iterable of strings.

Comment: That code does not return an error for me, neither in py2 nor py3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An enumerate object will have the form (internally)

```
months = [
    (0, '====='),
    (1, 'January),
    ...
]
```

The string `join` method expects a sequence of *strings* to join. However, it gets a sequence of *tuples*, so, gives an error.

Since join *needs* a list of strings, create a string for each option of your menu, and join them then. Something like

```
options = [f'<option value="{index}">{name}</option>' for index, value in enumerate(months)]
```

The `options` list will have the format

```
[
     '<option value="1">January</option>',
     '<option value="2">February</option>'
     ...]
```

So, you just join it with an empty string, and surrount it with the `select` elements.

```
select = '<select>' + ''.join(options) + '</select>'
```

This is your `select` element, as a string. Since it is a string, you can add anything you want before or after it

```
pdata = "<h1>διαλεξε μηνα</h1>" + select + "<button>στειλε φορμα</button>"
```

(this works in python 3.6+. if you are in an older version, use the appropriate string formatting).

Comment: To clarify i want the user to be able to open a dropdown menu listing the name of the months and when the user actually selects one month, then, the corresponding value of that month to be passed in the form data.

Comment: Thank you a lot but this actually confuses me. Where should i place this line? Substitute what lien of code with this one?

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος: this is your final `pdata` variable. it contains the whole `<select>` HTML string.

Comment: like this you mean? i've redietd my 1st post. Since i'am also calculatiing names and years dropdown menus coudl you please alter those lines too? It doesnt run as it is for the monent. Thank you!

Comment: Also for the sake of sanity, although your code is way too advanced for me, i would like to retain the syntax i was already using, that being `pdata = pdata + '''<select name="name"><option>  %s </option></select>''' % '</option><option>'.join( months )`

Comment: TypeError: must be str, not NoneType it says when it comes to pass the 'month' variable value. ill re-edit the 1st post to show how i have it after your suggestion.

Comment: How can i write 'options = [f'<option value="{index}">{name}</option>' for index, value in enumerate( months )]' with the use of '%s' operator ? could we please just use a for to create the selection menu? This line is nice but its complex.

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος: you need two `%s` operators, and format with `%(index, value)`. However, this is simpler syntax, it shows the name of  the variables, instead of some random `%s`

Comment: Also, you pass `months` (your list), not `month` (which is empty)

Comment: ` for i, month in enumerate(months):
 if i != 0:
  print( '<option value="%s"> %s </option>' % (i, month) )
 else:
  print( '<option value="%s"> %s </option>' % ('==========', month) )` Will this work? Why when i post code it doesnt print it with balnk lines and all like in the initial question post?

Comment: Thanks for your code, time and effort, i appreciate it!

Comment: Just out of curiocity how can we paste code with blank lines and everything within comments? backticks isn't supporting blank lines?